# Android ProgressBar that can go up and down?

Tags: java, android

I'm not sure how to search for this, as I don't know the words to describe what I'm looking for, but let me do my best!

I'm looking to see if there is a way to make a custom Progress bar on my android app. I know there is  but this seems to just measure percent of time that has elapsed. I'm looking for a bar that will actively go up and down in percent based on much a task has been completed per minute. In other words, if person does X a bunch of times it'll go up, but when the user slows down in completing X the bar goes down.

Any idea what this might be called or how to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: setProgress(int) allows you to set the progress to any value (even lower than the previous one).

Comment: Without knowing more on what you're trying to acheive, it's hard to give you a proper answer. You can use a `ProgressBar`, as Gnurfos mentionned, that will see its progress decrease.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to measure your activity X in executions per minute.

If you set a maximum execution value, you can then take those values and calculate your current percentage and set this value in your progress bar.